# Does mod_mono support web.config inheritance?

Tags: inheritance, mono, web-config, apache2, mod-mono

I'm having trouble getting a .NET web service to pick up values from its parent's web.config file.

The server is a debian machine running apache2 and mod_mono.  Applications are registered with mono-server4.

The parent service is registered as:

```
path = /path/to/service/Parent
alias = /Parent
```

The child service is registered as

```
path = /path/to/service/Parent/Child
alias = /Parent/Child
```

Both the Parent and the Child have their own web.config file.  The setting I'm trying to access is:

```
<configuration>
   <appSettings>
      <add key="Test" value="My Test Value" />
```

The code I'm using is:

```
System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Test"];
```

If the key is located in the Child's web.config, the Child service is able to retrieve the value.

If the key is located in the Parent's web.config, the Child service does not see the value.

Normally, under IIS, the Child service would inherit values from its Parent's web.config.

Does mod_mono support this?  Am I missing something in configuring the system?

Thanks,
Chris.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a bug then, you should report it in http://bugzilla.xamarin.com/